# OpenCV counting boundary boxes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, anaconda

what i'm trying to achieve is to count the boundary boxes of cv2.drawContours. 
Previously i have tried many solutions such as CV_RETR_EXTERNAL to retrieve the external contours, what i've been trying to achieve is a simple word count (Not a letter count). Using the logic of just counting the contours, i can achieve the word count. But the problem lies in the code to count the countour boundary box.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as pt

test1 = cv2.imread("test5.png") # Read image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(test1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert the image to grayscale
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)   # Apply Gaussian to reduce noise

# Apply threshold to extract the words from the image 
threshold=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,15,15)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (6,6))   # Create a structure element 
dilate = cv2.dilate(threshold, kernel, iterations = 1)  # Apply dilation to the image 
contour, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contour = cv2.drawContours(test1, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
pt.figure()
pt.imshow(threshold, cmap="gray")
pt.title("Threshold")
pt.figure()
pt.imshow(dilate, cmap="gray")
pt.title("Dilate")
pt.figure()
pt.imshow(test1, cmap="gray")
pt.title("Contour")

i = np.array((),dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(contour):
    i += contour
    print(i)
```

The error received is TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. I'm still new to coding and this is a challenging problem.

[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO3bu.png)

[Boundary Boxes Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1byZ.png)

Comment: “The error received is...” Where does the error occur? Also, what is that last `for` loop for?

Comment: The last loop is for the word counting the amount of words based on the boundary box. My logic is that the defined contour is linked to the cv2.drawContours, therefore if each cv2.drawContours is a boundary box i can count the amount of words.

Comment: I’m guessing that it doesn’t run because the program errors out and crashes first? Using `i` both for an array and then immediately after for a loop counter is a bad idea, I would really recommend changing that. I find that loop odd, I’m quite curious to see what it would output.

Comment: It would also be good if you could share the test image you’re using. See: [mcve].

Comment: I have added the images, i will try to test the codes and search for examples while practicing the code.

Comment: I think i have an inspiration after reading some IEEE papers, to allocate the boundary boxes into arrays and just loop the counter to count each x,y of said array, thus allowing the image to count all the words.

Comment: I have made progressto the answer., if you look at the code and process the image.
You will find out that it is a scalar value with 3 planes (B,G,R)
By seperating the green channel only. Then using a threshold method to remove every value that has a boundary of 255. And then you count from it using a for loop using a structuring element where the OCR(Optical Character Resolution) uses a hysteris threshold method of boundaries with 255 and neighbouring borders that are less than 255 on both the left and right of [x,y] coordinates you can count the words. But how do i translate it to code.

Comment: I think it is redundant to check the image word count using boundary box image processing, 
If i just save the file in a pdf then i can do the same using pdfminer. Ahhh the difficulties of coding and the dissapointments.

Comment: please improve your post. do not add information by comments. a bounding box is a box, usually a rectangle. you are referring to the contours. you don't have to count the contours because you already have their count as you have a list of contours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv2.findContours returns a Python list. In order to get the number of contours you don't have to count them, you just get the length of the list.

```
contour, _ = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contour))
```